# how to join centos 7 to samba domain?

Tags: ldap, samba, openldap, centos7, pam-ldap

In my office, we use samba domain + ldap. I already join some Windows 7 machines, but now I need to join CentOS 7 to that domain. How can I do that?

Below are steps that I already did:

1. install nss-pam-ldap.x86_64
2. configure smb.conf in /etc/samba/
3. configure all files in /etc/pam.d/, that call pam_unix.so to call and pam_ldap.so
4. add ldap to paswd, shadow and group lines in nsswich.conf
5. configure nslcd.conf

When i try to join with:

```
net join -U administrator
```

I get this:

> cannot join standalone machine

When I run

```
journalcrl -r
```

I get some pam_ldap error:

> pam_ldap: error opening connection to nslcd: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

Krisko.
First you have to install the packages for an sssd integration:

```
yum install \
realmd \
sssd \
sssd-krb5 \
sssd-krb5-common \
sssd-common \
sssd-common-pac \
sssd-ad \
sssd-proxy \
sssd-tools \
python-sssdconfig \
samba \
samba-common \
authconfig \
authconfig-gtk
```

Then create the machine account in an AD container your user ([Domain UID]) has full access to.

Add the machine to the domain:
realm --verbose join [FQ Domain name] -U [Domain UID]

Adjust /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
domains = <FQ Domain name lowercase>
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/bdp.pt]
ad_domain = <FQ Domain name lowercase>
krb5_realm = <FQ Domain name uppercase>
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = <Comma separated list of AD groups allowed to login in the form <FQDomainLowercase>\<GroupName>>
simple_allow_users = <Same for users>
```

You may have to adjust these 2 sections of /etc/krb5.conf

```
[realms]
 <FQDomainUpperCase> = {
 }

[domain_realm]
 <FQDomainLowerCase> = <FQDomainUpperCase>
 .<FQDomainLowerCase> = <FQDomainUpperCase>
```

Then this will no longer be a standalone machine, and you may authenticate domain users.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Goulart, but in my case was not helpful, but i have some progress. Now when i run command:
net join -U administrator, it says failed to join domain: failed to find DC for domain EXAMPLE.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can ping between your hosts, try both `ping server` and `ping server.domain.local`. In case you get nothing there, try specifying your KDC explicity in the kerberos config and in *smb.conf*.

Example of *krb5.conf* file:

```
/etc/krb5.conf
...
[realms]
         DOMAINNAME.COM = {
                 kdc = din-dc1.domainname.com
                 kdc = den-dc1.domainname.com
                 master_kdc = din-dc1.domainname.com
                 admin_server = din-dc1.domainname.com
         }

[domain_realm]
         .domainname.com = DOMAINNAME.COM
...

/etc/samba/smb.conf
...
[global]
         server string = Dinamo File Server

         workgroup = DOMAINNAME
         realm = DOMAINNAME.COM
         security = ADS
         password server = *
         #password server = din-dc1.domainname.com
         #password server = din-dc1.domainname.com, den-dc1.domainname.com
```

Use `kinit` to make sure kerberos is working!